# Execute ajax when html element visible on user screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this script which makes ajax request when user reaches the end of the page. It is based on scroll event. At page load I am showing only 16 products on the user screen and when he scrolls down I wish to load another 16 products. My script is working but it executes more than one ajax request which is not what I want. The idea is just to show another set of 16 products. The script is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.made').offset().top) {
        //here I count how many products I have shown already   
        var productsshown = $(".productcell").length;
        $('.made').hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "./ajax/get_more_products.php",
            data: {
                "product": productsshown
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#bcontent").html(data);
                $('.made').show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see I have a div which I am using as controler and when user see this div - the ajax is being executed. The result from ajax is being loaed into another div with `id="content"`

How to avoid scroll event to execute the ajax call more than once? I tried by hiding my controller div .made and upon ajax responce I am showing it again so it can be executed for another 16 products when user goes down to it again.. but ajax is always called executed more than once as I want it..

Comment: Your URL is not a string...: `url: ./ajax/get_more_products.php",` (missing opening quote). Please fix your errors.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake, I will fix it

Comment: heh, always check your code on quotations... dont copy paste everything blindly and asume it's correct. For your main question, set up an variable with a number, and whenever you run it, trigger it. whenever the item is higher, make it so the if statement cant get there.

Comment: You disable the scroll event until first ajax is complete and its content added.

Comment: Salman A, can you provide a sample code please? I think this will work out..

Answer (score 2):

hmm, Here is a small addition to your code, adding a flag swiched whenever you load more items:

```
var _itemsLoading = false;
if ((!_itemsLoading) && ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.made').offset().top)) {
    //here I count how many products I have shown already   
    var productsshown = $(".productcell").length;
    $('.made').hide();
    _itemsLoading = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "./ajax/get_more_products.php",
        data: {
            "product": productsshown
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#bcontent").html(data);
            $('.made').show();
            _itemsLoading = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple store the timestamp then you fire your ajax request and reset it then it returns or after 2 seconds.... then the timestamp is set don't fire your requests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't handle the scroll event. I use setInterval() and I test if the position has changed since previous tic.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('.made').offset().top) {
```

with:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
```

and used the page bottom as ajax controller.. It works now, thanks !